# Motherboard turns off and back on after I power it on (false start)

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

The computer is off. I press the power switch. After 1,5 seconds, the lights turn on, fans begin to spin. A second later, it shuts down. Another second later, it turns itself back on and boots successfully. What is happening with it?

- Motherboard: Gigabyte H360M GAMING HD
- PSU: Gigabyte PW400 80 Plus 400w
- i3-8100 w/ UHD Graphics 630
- 8 GB of DDR4-2400 Mhz RAM
- Case pins for power leds and switches are correctly installed according to markings on the motherboard indicated where each should go.

All components brand new. Recently assembled. Problem always reproducible.

Comment: I would try another psu.

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix it so far? Have you swapped any of the hardware components out with others to try to narrow down a source of the issue?

Comment: At first I thought the CMOS was being reset, but it is holding all my settings. The little battery is new. Would the PSU cause this? After it boots, I can use it for hours and hours, even gaming. It never shuts down or anything.

Comment: This behavior is normal on some Intel boards.

Comment: I've seen mixed conclusions about this behavior online. Some said it is normal, while others blamed PSU, CPU, Mobo, bad/missing grounding, etc. I tried a different PSU, same behavior. Changed the CMOS battery, same behavior. Checked for anything shorting the motherboard inside the case and reseated everything, no change. So I will simply acknowledge that this is a normal behavior, but it should be documented somewhere so we don't have to spend hours searching from unoficial sources.

Comment: I know there is one specific motherboard manufacturer where this behavior is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with Gigabyte eSupport, and they explained to me that, when the board stays unpowered for a while, turning it on will cause it to perform a false start in order to properly power up everything. So it is normal.